# Why does pandas.DataFrame.groupby(function) work when the function returns the Timestamp.date method itself instead of calling it?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, python-descriptors

In the following example, pandas.Dataframe.groupby() works the same whether or
not the date() method of the timestamp is explicitly called.  Why?  I expected
the explicit call to be required.

```py
import pandas as pd

def return_date_method(timestamp):
    return timestamp.date

def call_date_method(timestamp):
    return timestamp.date()

df = pd.DataFrame(range(4),
                  index=pd.date_range('2022', freq='12h', periods=4))

print(f'Using Pandas version {pd.__version__}')
print(df)
print()
print('return_date_method(df.index[0]) returns', return_date_method(df.index[0]))
print('call_date_method(df.index[0]) returns', call_date_method(df.index[0]))
print()
print(df.groupby(return_date_method).groups)
print()
print(df.groupby(call_date_method).groups)
```

Output:

```
Using Pandas version 0.25.3
                     0
2022-01-01 00:00:00  0
2022-01-01 12:00:00  1
2022-01-02 00:00:00  2
2022-01-02 12:00:00  3

return_date_method(df.index[0]) returns <built-in method date of Timestamp object at 0x00000233478574C8>
call_date_method(df.index[0]) returns 2022-01-01

{datetime.date(2022, 1, 1): DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01 00:00:00', '2022-01-01 12:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='12H'), datetime.date(2022, 1, 2): DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-02 00:00:00', '2022-01-02 12:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='12H')}

{datetime.date(2022, 1, 1): DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01 00:00:00', '2022-01-01 12:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='12H'), datetime.date(2022, 1, 2): DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-02 00:00:00', '2022-01-02 12:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='12H')}
```

This example shows that the behavior is different when using str.isalpha().

```py
def return_isalpha_method(string):
    return string.isalpha

def call_isalpha_method(string):
    return string.isalpha()

df2 = pd.DataFrame(range(4), index=list('1a2b'))
print(df2)
print()
print(df2.groupby(call_isalpha_method).groups)
print()
try:
    print(df2.groupby(return_isalpha_method).groups)
except TypeError as exception:
    print('TypeError:', exception)
```

Output:

```
   0
1  0
a  1
2  2
b  3

{False: Index(['1', '2'], dtype='object'), True: Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')}

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```